# VB.net forms application... what event to use when loading initial data

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms

I'm writing a forms application.  I'm adding a piece that allows you to double click on a row of a datagridview control to open a new form with more details.  These additional details are pulled from a database, which takes a bit of time to finish.

If I run the DB query from the form's load event, the form doesn't show up until everything in the load event has completed, which can take several seconds.

I want the form to show up instantly when you double click, and all of the fields to be populated once the data is ready.

Is there an event I should be using other than Load?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to accomplish this is to use a [background worker thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and disable the button until the worker thread completes. There is a complete event you can subscribe to on the background worker.

Answer (score 0):

You should use threading. Kick off a thread to do the data retrieval in the form's load event. [Introduction to threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `BackgroundWorker` to load the data in a background thread without freezing the UI.

If you really want to load on the UI thread, you should handle the `Shown` event.

Comment: Thanks, I figured threading was probably the way to go.  I tried out the backgroundworker suggestion, but I'm running into the same annoying problem I run into every time I attempt to mess with threading.   I'm pulling the data from the database in the backgroundworker thread, then populating the fields on the form with the data.  But because those fields were created on a different thread (mostly textboxes), my application errors out.

Basically set up like this:
**form_load - backgroundworker.runworkerasync()|
backgroundworker_dowork - get_data()|
get_data() - query DB, populate textboxes**

Comment: @arc: You need to call `BeginInvoke` to run on the UI thread, or pass the results to the Completed event (see `BackgroundWorker` documentation)

Comment: Yeah, that's where I start getting absolutely lost in threading.. I guess I'll keep trying to figure it out.  Delegates confuse me like nothing else.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an c# example using `BackgroundWorker` as the other posts metioned that loads unit definitions from `.xml` an file and changes the status label when it finishes. I stuck in the form intializer, but maybe it is better to start it in an `OnLoad()` override.

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new  RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        unitsToolStripLabel.Text = "Loading Units";
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        unitsToolStripLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} Units Loaded", Units.UnitLibrary.WorkingSet.Count);
        unitsToolStripLabel.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.HoverUnderline;
        unitsToolStripLabel.Click += new EventHandler(unitsToolStripLabel_Click);
    }
```

Please explain a little more on why you do not want to use threading/backgroundworker?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the correct way to do this is the BackgroundWorker thread, a quick and dirty method is to start a timer on the Load event and get the data when the timer expires. Say 10ms is enough for the form to be painted, then you can disable the controls and set the cursor busy while you get the data. But this is still going to lock up the UI thread while the database is busy leading to repainting artifacts eg if part of the window is covered, and doesn't allow you to display progress using a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the load event finish, then start another method to pull data from your database.  The initialization of the UI can be done after the form has completed loading, but make sure your UI controls are disabled while you're initializing them.